# igraph in R: error with get.shortest.paths but not with shortest.paths

Tags: r, igraph

I have encountered strange behavior using igraph in R.
`shortest.paths` command returns correct results, `get.shortest.paths` returns warning and no results.

```
shortest.paths(g, v=2795, to=2839) # correct

         [,1]
    [1,] 3930.4

get.shortest.paths(g, from=2795, to=2839) # warning and no results

    [[1]]

    numeric(0)

Warning message:
In get.shortest.paths(g_novy, from = 2795, to = 2839) :
  At structural_properties.c:5296 :Couldn't reach some vertices
```

Does anyone know, whats the problem?

Thanks,
Zbynek

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you have a directed graph. The `shortest.paths` function will tell you the length of the shortest undirected path. The `get.shortest.paths` function tells you that there is no directed path between the vertices. Below is the simplest example of what seems to be happening:

```
g <- graph(1:2)
plot(g)
shortest.paths(g, v=2, to=1)
#       [,1]
#  [1,]    1
get.shortest.paths(g, from=2, to=1)
#  [[1]]
#  numeric(0)
#  
#  Warning message:
#  In get.shortest.paths(g, from = 2, to = 1) :
#    At structural_properties.c:706 :Couldn't reach some vertices
```

Comment: Great! Thanks, that was the problem